# Integral by substitution does not work

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't know where I am getting it wrong.

I have this integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-0.5t}\left(1-(1-f)e^{-zt}\right)dt
$$
where $z>1$ and $f\in(0,1)$. I can solve directly this integral
and it is clearly well defined because of the term $e^{-0.5t}$ that
makes it do not explode. Fine, but for some reason I need to this
by substitution, doing $u(t)=1-(1-f)e^{-zt}$. Now I have
$$
dt=\frac{du}{z(1-u)}
$$

and 
$$
t=-\frac{1}{z}\log\left(\frac{1-u}{1-f}\right)\implies e^{-0.5 t}=\left(\frac{1-u}{1-f}\right)^{\frac{0.5}{z}}
$$

This gives the following integral
$$
\frac{1}{z}(1-f)^{-\frac{0.5}{z}}\int_{f}^{1}\left(1-u\right)^{\frac{0.5-z}{z}}udu
$$

But this clearly explores when $u\rightarrow1$ and does it does not
have a solution, although it should be equivalent to the first integral.

Answer (score 0):

From your expression here:

$$
dt=\frac{du}{z(1-u)},
$$

as $u \to 1$ your denominator blows up.

Comment: Why is that a problem? I mean, my expression for dt is defined for all values on my integration limits (which is the interval (f,1)).